# Unable migrate using Flyway 1.6 in Spring application

Tags: spring, flyway

I have Roo-generated Spring MVC application connected to PostgreSQL using Hibernate. I am trying to integrate Flyway 1.6 as a bean into Spring application context. "Something prevents" migrations from being executed and I'm getting error on context initialization caused by Hibernate metadata validation.
There are no problems performing migrations using Flyway 1.6 Maven plugin (clean, init, migrate).

Integration of Flyway 1.5 (previous version) works just fine.

What should I do in order to make Flyway 1.6 integrated migrations work?
What additional configuration should I provide?

Environment: Ubuntu 11.10, Springsource Tool Suite 2.9.1 (Eclipse 3.7.2), OpenJDK 6b23, Tomcat 7.0.23, PostgreSQL 8.4.9/9.1, Spring 3.0/3.1, Hibernate 3.6.4.Final, PostgreSQL Native Driver 8.4 JDBC3/4 build 702.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <classifier/>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/library</url>
                <baseDir>db/migration</baseDir>
                <user>library</user>
                <password>library</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

database.properties:

```
database.password=library
database.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/library
database.username=library
database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Spring context configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ...>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="edu.sandbox.library">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT version();"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="flyway" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<bean class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" id="flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

log:

```
...
INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19d03a4e: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,dataSource,transactionManager,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAspect,entityManagerFactory,flyway]; root of factory hierarchy
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory - Database: PostgreSQL
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway - Schema: public
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.ClassPathScanner - Scanning directory: file:/home/developer/projects/sandbox/t7-work/webapps/library/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration/
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.ClassPathScanner - Scanning directory: file:/home/developer/projects/sandbox/t7-work/webapps/library/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration/
INFO  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'persistenceUnit'
...
INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata - table not found: book
INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@43a4181c: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,dataSource,transactionManager,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAspect,entityManagerFactory,flyway]; root of factory hierarchy
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in file [/.../applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [/.../applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you could be facing the same issue as this: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/107

Please give the attached jar a test. If it also works for you, I'll release it as 1.6.1 in the next few days.

Comment: Everything works fine with [flyway-core-1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=242#c4).
Thanks a lot. Looking forward to next release of Flyway - an extremely valuable DB migration tool. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Always makes me happy :-) 1.6.1 is out with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Adding trailing `/` to `baseDir` property value ([as mentioned](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=239)) seems to be a workaround for Flyway 1.6:

```
<bean class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" id="flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="baseDir" value="db/migration/"/>
</bean>
```

Migrations run as expected, producing following log:

```
...
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory - Database: PostgreSQL
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway - Schema: public
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.ClassPathScanner - Scanning directory: file:/home/developer/projects/sandbox/t7-work/webapps/library/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration/
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.ClassPathScanner - Found resource: db/migration/V1__initial.sql
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.ClassPathScanner - Scanning directory: file:/home/developer/projects/sandbox/t7-work/webapps/library/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration/
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.ClassPathScanner - Scanning directory: file:/home/developer/projects/sandbox/t7-work/webapps/library/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration/
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.ClassPathScanner - Found resource: db/migration/V1__initial.sql
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.ClassPathScanner - Scanning directory: file:/home/developer/projects/sandbox/t7-work/webapps/library/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration/
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.sql.SqlScript - Found statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE public.schema_version (
...
DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.sql.SqlStatement - Executing SQL: CREATE INDEX schema_version_current_version_index ON public.schema_version (current_version)
INFO  com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTable - Metadata table created: schema_version (Schema: public)
INFO  com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.DbMigrator - Current schema version: null
INFO  com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.DbMigrator - Migrating to version 1
...
INFO  com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.DbMigrator - Successfully applied 1 migration (execution time 00:00.161s).
...
```