# Flyway not finding migraions only in my jar file

Tags: java, migration, flyway

I have a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226070/flyway-not-finding-the-migrations-in-a-jar-file) but I've migrate to version 2.1.1 and the problem are still here.
I just do something like that

```
 Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setLocations(MIGRATION_PACKAGES);
    flyway.setDataSource(getDatasource());
    flyway.setTable("schema_version");
    flyway.setSqlMigrationPrefix("v");
    flyway.migrate();
```

There is no problem with that cause all work fine in my IDE, but when I package in jar, that not found my migrations ...
any ideas ?

Edit: I've already test to put my jar who contain the migration in dependency of a test app who just migrate and the migrations are apply fine ... I don't know what i can do.

Edit I've enabled the FINEST logging and at the moment to find migration

```
FINE: Scanning for resources at 'db/migration' (Prefix: 'v', Suffix: '.sql')
juil. 10, 2013 4:44:53 PM com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner findResourceNames
FINE: Unable to determine URL for classpath location: db/migration (ClassLoader: java.net.URLClassLoader@6458c2)
juil. 10, 2013 4:44:53 PM com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner scanForClasses
FINE: Scanning for classes at 'db/migration' (Implementing: 'com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration')
juil. 10, 2013 4:44:53 PM com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner findResourceNames
FINE: Unable to determine URL for classpath location: db/migration (ClassLoader: java.net.URLClassLoader@6458c2)
juil. 10, 2013 4:44:53 PM com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner scanForResources
FINE: Scanning for resources at 'com/me/myapp/sql/migration' (Prefix: 'v', Suffix: '.sql')
juil. 10, 2013 4:44:53 PM com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner findResourceNames
FINE: Unable to determine URL for classpath location: com/me/myapp/sql/migration (ClassLoader: java.net.URLClassLoader@6458c2)
juil. 10, 2013 4:44:53 PM com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner scanForClasses
FINE: Scanning for classes at 'com/me/myapp/sql/migration' (Implementing: 'com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration')
juil. 10, 2013 4:44:53 PM com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner findResourceNames
FINE: Unable to determine URL for classpath location: com/me/myapp/sql/migration (ClassLoader: java.net.URLClassLoader@6458c2)
```

Comment: the debug say nothing, I just have a log before creating the flyway instance who I add, and after this log nothing is print.. that why it's weird. but when I launch on the app test or from my IDE there is no problems migration are done. And it's not on a server, it's a local app with one H2 database.

Comment: yes I display my classpath just before creating my flyway instance. And on my jar I have the sql/migration package here with all migrations. That why I realy don't understand the problem

Comment: I try to clone the git repo and add more log, maybe I'll see the problem ..

Comment: What is the value MIGRATION_PACKAGES ?

Answer (score 1):

The default name of the scanned location is `db/migration`, not `sql/migrations`. If you want to use `sql/migrations` instead, set:

`flyway.setLocations("sql/migrations");`