# Why flyway remove slashe to the end of my location

Tags: java, migration, flyway

refered to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474096/flyway-not-finding-migraions-only-in-my-jar-file) I discover flyway remove the slashes of the end of location path with the method normalizeLocation. (On Flyway 1.7)
In debug mode when flyway call findResourceNames if I evaluate

```
getClassLoader().getResources("com/me/app/sql/migration").hasMoreElements();
```

it's always return false. But if I evaluate

```
getClassLoader().getResources("com/me/app/sql/migration/").hasMoreElements();
```

it's return true.

So why flyway doing this ? cause it's probably the source of my problem, and cause of that my migration are never find.

Comment: What `normalizeLocation` method are you talking about?  There is no such method in flyway 2.2 javadoc index.

Comment: sorry i'm back to the 1.7 version of flyway

Comment: Please upgrade to 2.2 and try again. It fixes many issues.

Comment: it's already the same thing in 2.2. if I test getLocationUrlsForPath("com/me/app/sql/migration") no url found but getLocationUrlsForPath("com/me/app/sql/migration/") the url are found. and flyway remove the last "/" so it can't works

Comment: Please file a bug in the issue tracker. Don't forget to include what environment are you on (OS, JDK, AppServer + versions)